# getting Not clickable exception (Element <select class="form-control" name="statusDropdown"> is not clickable at point)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

1.Actually last 2days im trying to solve this exception but still it' not working. So please suggest what could be the issue even if I'm using correct xpath but i'm still getting this exception.

2. I'm using below xPath

```
deliveryChannel=//statusdropdown[@id="deliveryChannelField"]//select
```

for this xpath i'm getting exception , this Xpath i'm using in test `case (Test(priority = 4))`

```
printStatus = //statusdropdown[@id="releaseStatusDropDown"]//select
```

No exception here

```
@Test(priority = 4)
    public void deliveryChannel() throws InterruptedException {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        
        String getDeliveryChannel = sftpCon.deliveryChannel("Search Criteria", 0);
    //WebElement deliveryChannelDropDown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("deliveryChannel"))));
        WebElement deliveryChannelDropDown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("deleverysize"))));
        System.out.println("Delevery Channel Text = "+deliveryChannelDropDown.getText());
        select = new Select(deliveryChannelDropDown);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> listSelectApp = select.getOptions();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSelectApp.size(); i++) {
            String app = listSelectApp.get(i).getText();
            if (getDeliveryChannel.contains(app)) {
                listSelectApp.get(i).click();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 5, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
    public void getPrintStatus() throws InterruptedException {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        String printStatus = sftpCon.deliveryChannel("Search Criteria", 1);
        WebElement printStatusDropDown = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("printStatus"))));
        select = new Select(printStatusDropDown);
        List<WebElement> listSelectApp = select.getOptions();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSelectApp.size(); i++) {
            String app = listSelectApp.get(i).getText();
            if (printStatus.contains(app)) {
                listSelectApp.get(i).click();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Below are my html element**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<statusdropdown id="deliveryChannelField" ng-reflect-selected-status="print" ng-reflect-optional-status="[object Object]" ng-reflect-return-key="delivery_channel_name" ng-reflect-display-key="delivery_channel_description">
<select class="form-control" name="statusDropdown">
<!--bindings={  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}-->
<option value="print" ng-reflect-value="print">Print</option>
</select>
</statusdropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share html elements dom for that particular element which you are trying to interect ?

Comment: Please check i have added html elemnts

Comment: You have to use the element with select tag when using Select.
Use name="statusDropdown" element in select = new Select(name).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()`, I think you could use `elementToBeClickable()`. If this doesn't work, then I think there's something with that website and you'll have to edit your question to provide the website as well.